# Assistance required with Cirkle theme functionality

Tags: wordpress

**I'm encountering a challenge with the "Cirkle theme" in WordPress**[image: Page where the professional should be displayed] that I have been unable to resolve despite numerous attempts.
Attached is an image that illustrates the problem I'm facing.

## **Here is the situation: I aim to display the profiles of all users assigned the "Professional" role on the "Get Help" page. To achieve this, I have been utilizing "BuddyPress" to aid in the display process, yet, the desired outcome remains elusive. On the page I can only see 3 users displayed out off 10 users but the remaining 7 users are invisible. **

I am seeking guidance or solutions to this issue.

Please help me.